# Change HTML attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery 1.4.4. and I have this source code:

```
<div id="area1">
    <ul id="testlist" data-filter="false">

    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I change the data-filter attribute to true in jQuery?
I tried for example:

```
$('#testlist').attr("data-filter").val(true);
```

but it does not work.

Anyone an idea?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using `jQuery 1.4.4` and "data" attributes, you can use [jQuery's `.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/SLskn/

```
alert( $('#testlist').data("filter") ); // alerts "false"

$('#testlist').data("filter",true);

alert( $('#testlist').data("filter") ); // alerts "true"
```

*[From the docs:](http://api.jquery.com/data/)*

> As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object.

Answer (score 8):

The syntax for [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is `$.attr(attributeName, value);`. Try this:

```
$('#testlist').attr("data-filter", true);
```

Comment: And the benefit of this is that you still get chaining.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong syntax. Try this:

```
$('#testlist').attr("data-filter", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`$('#testlist').attr("data-filter", "true");`

Or possibly

`$('#testlist').attr("data-filter", true);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#testlist').attr("data-filter",true);
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

Try $('#testlist').attr("data-filter", "true"); instead

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage of .attr is `.attr(name, value)`

So change your code to

```
$('#testlist').attr("data-filter", true);
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

So you're using the HTML5 syntax for custom attributes... Nice.

There is a jQuery [metadata plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata) that allows you to access those attributes in a more semantic way. Just use it like this:

```
// Reading:
var tooltipTitle = $(".tooltip").metadata().filter;

// Writing:
$(".tooltip").metadata().filter = "whatever";
```